# Hide a bash function internals

Tags: linux, bash

My .bashrc looks something like this...

```
 export PERL5LIB="/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0/${PLAT}-thread-multi"
 export PERL5LIB="${PERL5LIB}:/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0"

 function dev {
   export PERL5LIB="/dev/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0/${PLAT}-thread-multi"
   export PERL5LIB="${PERL5LIB}:/dev/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0"
 }
```

The problem is that when I grep for PERL5LIB is see everything.

```
> env | grep PERL
PERL5LIB=/tools/perl/Linux/x86_64/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-thread-multi:/tools/perl/Linux/x86_64/lib/perl5/5.10.0
 export PERL5LIB="/dev/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0/${PLAT}-thread-multi";
 export PERL5LIB="${PERL5LIB}:/dev/tools/perl/Linux/${PLAT}/lib/perl5/5.10.0";
```

So it's picking up the stuff inside of my "dev" function.  Is there a way to hide the contents of a function?  Or do I just need to get used to getenv..  Old habits are hard to break..

Comment: Are you sure you're running "env" and not "set"? env only shows the environment, not bash functions.

Comment: Positive. I type it all the time! env | grep XYZ.  The problem is my .bash_profile has grown and it's tough to parse.

Comment: Glad you figured out what was going on -- would you mind explaining what the problem was somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `type env` at your bash prompt, and provide the output; for me, this indicates that env is `/usr/bin/env`, a separate executable; such executables have no way to know anything about functions or non-exported variables.

That said, without fixing the underlying problem (the likely cause being use of a bash built-in, function or alias in place of `/usr/bin/env`, which the output of the type command will show), there's a workaround available: `env | grep '^PERL'`; the caret will emit only lines beginning with `PERL` (as opposed to `PERL` anywhere in the line), and function contents are indented in output of `set` (which appears to be running in place of `env`; again, `type env` should give a clue to the cause).

One point of clarification: `set` is a bash builtin which, when run with no arguments, dumps defined variables (environment or otherwise) and functions; when run *with* arguments, it has some other, completely different (and POSIX-specified) behaviors. `env`, as an external program, has no access to unexported variables or to functions defined within the shell that calls it.

(set is actually not bash-specific, but rather is [specified by POSIX](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html) to dump all shell variables; its additional functionality of dumping function definitions is to my knowledge an extension beyond the letter of the standard).

Comment: Can you explain your second comment WRT "output of set"?  Thanks

Comment: ...and that's output from `type`, not `which`? If what's being invoked truly is `/usr/local/bin/env`, it has no way of knowing what your defined shell functions are, and thus no way of dumping them.

Comment: You led me to the answer!  Thanks!!

Comment: What will the carrot emit now? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
( set -o posix ; set )
```

Comment: I suppose you could have some fun with functions and aliases to have `env` always invoke that sequence when called without arguments -- but as I understand it, the goal here is to come up with a way for rh0dium to get the desired behavior *without changing his habits* (and thus the commandline he habitually pipes).